# can't save or build using VSCode in Dropbox-synced folder

Tags: dropbox, visual-studio-code

To start, I'm a programming noob and am not familiar with the more technical aspects of programming related things.

I use VS Code as my IDE of choice for LaTeX, with LaTeX Workshop. I store all my files in a Dropbox folder, which I access on two computers - my PC and my MBP. For whatever reason, when I'm on my PC, I can't save or build .tex files which were last edited on my laptop, and vice versa.

Does anyone know why this might be?